# Python Grocery List Python 3 Codio Challenge

Tags: python, codio

So I am looking for a way to add separate items to a list in the form of individual dictionaries that contain the grocery item's name, price, and quantity. I only started programming a few weeks ago so please forgive my horrendous code and beginner mistakes.

```
grocery_item = dict()
current_item = dict()
grocery_history = []
choice = 0
stop = True
while stop == True:
    current_item['name'] = str(input('Item name: '))
    current_item['quantity'] = int(input('Amount purchased: '))
    current_item['cost'] = float(input('Price per item: '))
    grocery_history.append(current_item)
    choice = str(input('Press c to continue or q to quit'))
    if choice == 'c':
        stop = True
    else:
        stop = False
 print(grocery_history)
```

When I input the information of two items (ie spam and eggs) I get the following output:

```
[{'name': 'Eggs', 'quantity': 12, 'cost': 1.5}, {'name': 'Eggs', 'quantity': 
12, 'cost': 1.5}]
```

Instead of creating two different items the output just repeats the most recent one I entered. I am making some basic semantic error and I can't figure out how to populate the "grocery_history" list with different items from the user input loop. I tried using pythontutor.com for help but was just berated for being stupid. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You always reuse the same `current_item` dict. You have to create a new one in each iteration of your loop, otherwise you overwrite the values in the old one.

Comment: You always `grocery_history.append(current_item)`  but `current_item` **always refers to the same dictionary**. So you are merely appending the same dictionary to the `grocery_history` list multiple times.

Comment: How do I go about creating a new dictionary with each iteration? Can someone provide an example of how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
grocery_item = dict()
grocery_history = []
choice = 0
stop = True
while stop == True:
    current_item = dict()
    current_item['name'] = str(input('Item name: '))
    current_item['quantity'] = int(input('Amount purchased: '))
    current_item['cost'] = float(input('Price per item: '))
    grocery_history.append(current_item)
    choice = str(input('Press c to continue or q to quit'))
    if choice == 'c':
        stop = True
    else:
        stop = False
print(grocery_history)
```

By creating a new dictionary in each loop you'll avoid the duplicate error that you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks so much Connor and everyone else! I think I understand better now.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `current_item` dictionary into the `while`, for example:

```
while True:
    current_item = {}
    # accepts user inputs here
    grocery_history.append(current_item)
    choice = str(input('Press c to continue or q to quit'))
    if choice != 'c':
        break
```

Some other notes:

- No need to initiate `choice = 0` before the loop.
- Use `break` to stop the loop as soon as possible without going back to check the condition again

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because dictionaries in Python are mutable objects: this means that you can actually modify their fields without creating a brand new one.

Follow this [link](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) if you want to understand more deeply what are the main differences between mutable and immutable objects.

This is your code slightly modified, and working:

```
grocery_history = []
while True:
    name = input('Item name: ').strip()
    quantity = int(input('Amount purchased: '))
    cost = float(input('Price per item: '))
    current_item = {'name':name, 'quantity':quantity, 'cost':cost} 
    grocery_history.append(current_item)
    choice = str(input('Press c to continue or q to quit: '))
    if choice == 'q':
        break
print(grocery_history)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the link and the helpful response. I love this community already.